# Can Veracrypt decrypt disk after alter one bit from 0 to 1?

Tags: veracrypt

I use Veracrypt to encrypt my removable hard disk.As my removable hard disk is HDD,there's very little probability write 1 when should write 0.
If there's one bit error,can Veracypt successfully decrypt my removable hard disk?

Comment: Possibly: it might just change one character in a file, unnoticeable n i,mage or video, or it could corrupt the file system, leaving part unusable. Make backups of *anything*.